# Can't install "Web Developer Tools" on Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In the Visual Studio 2012 RC, I can't install Web Developer Tools properly. None of my ASP .NET MVC project will load in VS2012, and I can't create new ones. The option for ASP .NET MVC projects is simply not there, as shown below.

[image]

Furthermore, I can't pick any other framework than the .NET Framework 4 and earlier. I can't seem to pick .NET 4.5, but that may be because it's just an addition to .NET 4.0. That I don't know.

I'm running Windows 8 Release Preview, which should have .NET 4.5 RC installed already, so that shouldn't be the problem. Furthermore, if I click "I want to download more .NET redistributables", I'm taken to a site which says that Visual Studio 2012 RC has that included already.

I can't seem to download MVC 4.5 and install it separately. This is because they claim that it's included already in VS2012 as well.

When I try to click "Modify installation" in my Visual Studio 2012 RC installer, I see the following.

[image]

What's interesting here is that "Web developer tools" is never checked. If I check it and click "Update" and reboot, it's unchecked again, and it seems as if this whole feature is missing. I suppose that's really the cause of the problem.

I tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2012 RC entirely by first removing it, then rebooting, and then re-installing it. Running a setup repair doesn't work either.

I have managed to find no other examples of such a problem so far anywhere.

Can you help me?

**Edit 1**
I just found another weird symptom. Whenever I want to make a "Windows Metro Style" application, it doesn't work either, coming up with this message.

[image]

Like I said before, this may indeed be because it's not detecting that I have .NET 4.5 installed already, but I'm not sure. All I know is that I can't pick .NET 4.5 from the frameworks list at all.

Comment: I had a lot of similar issues with the web installer. Try the installer from the ISO file

Comment: "I uninstalled and then reinstalled everything.." did you uninstalled all Web tooling components in packages/WPT folder ,Or uninstalled vs11?

Comment: I uninstalled all of the packages in that folder and reinstalled them.

Comment: I have a similar issue in `Visual Studio Professional 2015`. The `Web Developer Tools` is always checked for me, even when I uninstall it; but not ASP.Net Template, No Javascript, Razor syntax highlighter, .. working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the ISO, I extracted the packages/WPT folder. Inside are all of the installers for the Web tooling components. I uninstalled and then reinstalled everything that had vs11 in the name and it worked!